# Best way to keep a constant stream of a local file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Okay, so I've been trying to use some sort of Javascript to constantly refresh a changing file to get updates in real-time without having to use node.js or socket.io because I don't have the capabilities to add it to my server.

I've been using the following code to combat this, but I would assume it is a ridiculous way of doing this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var st = setInterval(function(){
    $.get("api.php",{user:1});
}, 1000);
</script>
```

That is just a sum of it, I have a limit of 25 requests before it stopping and asking if you're still there.

Is there a better way to do this without a server-side addon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the file is monotonously increasing, you could ask the server for the difference. Start with offset 0, get the length of the returned file, add it to the running length, then ask for the file starting at that position. This way, you don't try to transport the whole file once a second, just discrete chunks that add up to the full file when you append them together.

Also, I don't like `setInterval` for things whose length I don't know; I'd prefer an auto-refreshing `setTimeout` (i.e. set current function to timeout after it has done doing whatever it had to do); this way, you can have a delay of 1 second between requests, instead of between beginnings of requests (which can start overlapping if the delay gets significant).

```
var getFromApi = function() {
  $.get("api.php", { user: 1 }, function() {
    setInterval(getFromApi, 1000);
  };
};
getFromApi();
```

Comment: The file doesn't accumulate, it is new things every time. It's javascript code that is run, and if the javascript is run, it sends a request to the server saying it's been executed, making the queue of information smaller.

Comment: In that case, I don't see why it wouldn't work (except for what I said about overlapping).